# How can I confine users to 1 choice in message reactions?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a poll command:

```js
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix+"poll")) {
    var poll = message.content.split(prefix+"poll");
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send(poll[1]+" \n\n @everyone").then(function(message) {
    message.react("");
    message.react("");
    });
}
```

but I want to allow the user to only react to 1 option, if the user reacts to more than 1 option it gets removed/reverted.

Comment: Are you using a reaction collector?

Comment: @Syntle no cause I don't know how to use

Comment: That's the problem. We can only help if you have already attempted to code it.